# How to download a specific revision of google slides file?

Tags: python, google-api, google-drive-api, google-slides-api

i'm trying to get a specific version of google slides, for that i first of all get all revisions:

```py
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(credentials_path)
drive_service = build("drive", "v2", credentials=creds)
revs = drive_service.revisions().list(fileId=presentation_id).execute()
revs_items = revs.get('items')
```

Then in variable `revs_items` contained all revisions, with all fields, including `exportLinks` with various versions of formats for export, but all of that links leads to downloading of latest version of file.

Revisions dicts looks like this:

```
{'etag': '"HYVl_XolCtT8iAhJReRS6HnNpU4"',
 'exportLinks': {'application/pdf': 'my_link&revision=2682&exportFormat=pdf',
                 'application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation': 'my_link&revision=2682&exportFormat=odp',
                 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation': 'my_link&revision=2682&exportFormat=pptx',
                 'text/plain': 'my_link&revision=2682&exportFormat=txt'},
 'id': '2682',
 'kind': 'drive#revision',
 'lastModifyingUser': {'displayName': '',
                       'isAuthenticatedUser': False,
                       'kind': 'drive#user'},
 'lastModifyingUserName': '',
 'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.presentation',
 'modifiedDate': '2021-10-29T09:02:29.011Z',
 'published': False,
 'selfLink': 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/my_link/revisions/2682'}

{'etag': '"tYdKGWZBKi1nzFMg_Rc_y4DMuEE"',
 'exportLinks': {'application/pdf': 'https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/presentations/Export?id=my_link&revision=2688&exportFormat=pdf',
                 'application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation': 'https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/presentations/Export?id=my_link&revision=2688&exportFormat=odp',
                 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation': 'https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/presentations/Export?id=my_link&revision=2688&exportFormat=pptx',
                 'text/plain': 'https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/presentations/Export?id=my_link&revision=2688&exportFormat=txt'},
 'id': '2688',
 'kind': 'drive#revision',
 'lastModifyingUser': ''},
 'lastModifyingUserName': '',
 'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.presentation',
 'modifiedDate': '2024-01-17T16:43:40.518Z',
 'published': False,
 'selfLink': 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/my_link/revisions/2688'}
```

Is there a way to download a specific version of file or google banned it?

Comment: Based on this [Google doc](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/manage-revisions#:~:text=Revisions%20for%20Google%20Docs%2C%20Sheets%2C%20and%20Slides%20can%27t%20be%20downloaded.), Revisions of Google files like  Google Docs, Sheets, and Slides can't be downloaded.

Comment: I'm worried that your situation might be related to [this issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36759589).

Comment: @Tanaike Oh, thank you, this is really the same problem. But unfortunately it wasn't fixed and people from the issue didn't found a workaround

Comment: Thank you for replying. In the current stage, this can be used to only Spreadsheets (to all mimeTypes) and Documents (only to PDF format). Unfortunately, it seems that this issue has still been resolved fir Slides.